# Java SWT table different cell values in a row

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, swt

I'm working on GUI with SWT and I have an issue with comparing cells in a row. I have a table with some information, most of the information in a row should be the same, but if there a different one I need to highlight it.
Look at my code here:

```
                          for(int x=0;x<tableConfigurationLP.getItemCount();x++) {
                          TableItem rowItem = tableConfigurationLP.getItem(x);
                          //int check = 0;
                          for(int i=1;i<tableConfigurationLP.getColumnCount();i++) {        
                              String colValue = rowItem.getText(i);
                              if(i>=2) {
                                  //if(check!=1) {
                                      if(!colValue.equals(rowItem.getText(i-1))) {
                                          rowItem.setBackground(i, Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
                                          //check+=1;
                                      }
                                //} 
                              }
                          }
                      }
```

**Picture of the output:**

[image]

What i need to change in my code to highlight only the different one? or maybe I need to save the row values somewhere and than check? I don't know how go next...

***EDIT:***
I've made some changes: I guess this is the answer

```
                          for(int x=0;x<tableConfigurationLP.getItemCount();x++) {
                          TableItem rowItem = tableConfigurationLP.getItem(x);
                          for(int i=1;i<tableConfigurationLP.getColumnCount();i++) {        
                              String colValue = rowItem.getText(i);
                                      if(!colValue.equals(rowItem.getText(1))) {
                                          rowItem.setBackground(i, Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
                                      }
                          }
                      }
```

Comment: What is supposed to be the problem here? Is it the 4th column of the table? What is supposed to be in the 4th column? It looks like at the moment the 4th column never equals the 3rd column.

Comment: I don't know, my software takes file, put the data to table and compare, if I press button to delete all the data and then upload another file it just add new columns to start index in table and don't delete the empty columns from before.

Comment: I'm edited the code.. but this error still occurs

Comment: I'm sorry but you keep giving us scraps of information and incomplete bits of code. It is impossible to help when we have no idea what you are trying to do and what is wrong. Edit your question and show us a **complete** [mcve]. Show us what you get and what you expected.